# jQuery Switchclass keeps switching back

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is to make a button on click, go to the top left slot in the crafting table on [this page](http://www.minecraftserverland.com/testview.php). Then if the element is clicked again it will go back. The specific jQuery I am using is:

```
$("#sword").click(function () {
    if ( $("#sword").hasClass("s1") ) {
        $('#sword.s1').switchClass( "s1", "sd1", 1000, "linear" );
    } else if (  $("#sword").hasClass("sd1") ) {
        $('#sword').switchClass( "sd1", "s1", 1000, "linear" );
        $('#bukkit').switchClass( "s1", "sd2", 1000, "linear" );
        $('#grass').switchClass( "s1", "sd3", 1000, "linear" );
    }
});
```

`sd1` is down below, `s1` is the slot above. As you can see currently it will bounce up and then immediately bounce back down. I have tried making bounce back down a separate function for when `.s1` is clicked, but then nothing would happen when I clicked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked your code on the page you linked to. You have bound two click handlers to `#sword`. You have only shown the first one.  Your code is as follows

```
$("#sword").click(function () { // handler 1
    if ( $("#sword").hasClass("s1") ) {
        $('#sword.s1').switchClass("s1", "sd1", 1000, "linear");
    } else if ($("#sword").hasClass("sd1")) {
        $('#sword').switchClass( "sd1", "s1", 1000, "linear" );
        $('#bukkit').switchClass( "s1", "sd2", 1000, "linear" );
        $('#grass').switchClass( "s1", "sd3", 1000, "linear" );
    }
});

// a few lines later    

$("#sword").click(function() { // handler 2
    $('#sword').switchClass( "s1", "sd1", 1000, "linear" );
    $('#bukkit').switchClass( "s1", "sd2", 1000, "linear" );
    $('#grass').switchClass( "s1", "sd3", 1000, "linear" );
});
```

Clicking on the sword executes handler 1 first and then handler 2. As is clear from the code, handler 1 moves it up and handler 2 brings it down.

If you explain why you wrote the second handler, I might be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really cant believe i didnt delete my previous try. I feel like http://static.divbyzero.nl/facepalm/doublefacepalm.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-order your `switchClass` classes of id `sword` is changed to `sd2` after it changes from `sd1` to `s1`

```
$("#sword").click(function () {

    if ( $("#sword").hasClass("s1") ) {
        $('#sword.s1').switchClass( "s1", "sd1", 1000, "linear" );
    } else if (  $("#sword").hasClass("sd1") ) {
        $('#bukkit').switchClass( "s1", "sd2", 1000, "linear" );
        $('#grass').switchClass( "s1", "sd3", 1000, "linear" );
        $('#sword').switchClass( "sd1", "s1", 1000, "linear" );
    }

});
```