# jQuery switch class not activating in Chrome correctly

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I'm making a feature on my site that uses jQuery's switch class function to animate buttons.

You can see the page at http://www.minecraftserverland.com/testview.php

The buttons go from having a white background to a clear background when clicked and back to a white background after being clicked a second time. This works perfectly in firefox and internet explorer but in google chrome, the switched classes don't seem to render properly.

The buttons do not turn clear and actually turn black when clicked a second time. However, during any point, if you inspect element, the classes fix themselves, so the javascript is obviously working properly.

An example of the jquery I am using:

```
$("#ftb").click(function () {
    if ( $("#ftb").hasClass("s1") ) {
        $('#ftb.s1').switchClass( "s1", "sd1", 700, "swing" );
        $('input#main').val('1');
    } else if (  $("#ftb").hasClass("sd1") ) {
        $('#ftb').switchClass( "sd1", "s1", 700, "swing" );
        $('#bukkit').switchClass( "s1", "sd2", 700, "swing" );
        $('#vanilla').switchClass( "s1", "sd3", 700, "swing" );
        $('input#main').val('ftb');
    }
});
```

Has anyone ever encountered this before? Do you know why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: I've seen other cases where Chrome renders something wrong after changing the class dynamically, and then it clears up when you inspect it. I think it's a Chrome bug.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Do you know @wl4000? Looks like he asked a different question about this same bit of code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138145/jquery-switchclass-keeps-switching-back?rq=1

Comment: The couple of times I've seen this before, I haven't figured out a workaround. Unfortunately, I can't find the SO questions that discussed them (you can only search questions and answers, not comments), so I don't know if someone else figured it out.

Comment: I do know him we are actually partners. Looks like no one has a solution to this unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same case.

Funny thing is that chrome acts normally when you use the old `.removeclass().addclass()` thingie. Typing it every time is iritating, so I made a simple funciton, without any callbacks or duration, hope it helps you guys.

```
jQuery.fn.switcher = function(n,s) {
    var $elem = $(this[0]) ;
    $(this).removeClass(n).addClass(s);

    return $elem; //ensures jquery chainability
};
```

works like this:

```
$(element).switcher("removedclass","addedclass");
```